# What causes this vector subscript out of range Error?

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, coordinates, sfml

I am currently mapping a Graph to a Minesweeper like grid, where every Block represents a node.
Here is my `Graph` class:

```
    class Graph : public sf::Drawable
    {
        public:
            Graph(uint32_t numNodesWidth, uint32_t numNodesHeight);

            [[nodiscard]] std::vector<Node> & operator[](std::size_t i) 
            { return data[i]; }


            [[nodiscard]] sf::Vector2u dimension() const 
            { return {static_cast<uint32_t>(data.size()), 
              static_cast<uint32_t>(data[0].size())};}
            ...
            ...
        private:
            std::vector<std::vector<Node>> data;
    };
```

here is the implementation of the constructor:

```
    Graph::Graph(uint32_t numNodesWidth, uint32_t numNodesHeight)
    {
        data.resize(numNodesHeight);
        for(auto & row : data)
        {
            row.resize(numNodesWidth);
        }
    }
```

Somewhere in another class I read mouse coordinates and convert them to "Graph Coordinates":

```
sf::Vector2u translatedCoords = toGraphCoords(sf::Mouse::getPosition(window), nodeSize_);
bool inBounds = checkGraphBounds(translatedCoords, graph.dimension());
```

Here are the helper functions:

```
        sf::Vector2u toGraphCoords(sf::Vector2i mouseCoord, sf::Vector2f nodeSize)
        {
            return {static_cast<uint32_t>(mouseCoord.y / nodeSize.y), 
                    static_cast<uint32_t>(mouseCoord.x / nodeSize.x)};
        }

        bool checkGraphBounds(sf::Vector2u mouseCoord, sf::Vector2u bounds)
        {
            return mouseCoord.x >= 0 && 
                    mouseCoord.y >= 0 && 
                    mouseCoord.x < bounds.x && 
                    mouseCoord.y < bounds.y ;
        }
```

Somehow I get the `vector subscript out of range 1655`  error when I try to use these new checked Coordinates which is somehow strange, can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong. This error always shows when I try to hover beyond the "Bounds" of the Interactive area, slightly behind or in front the first or the last Node.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should be easy enough to find with a debugger (GDB on Linux, VS on Windows). Does it show you the line of the code where it happens?

Comment: @pptaszni, unfortunately no.

Comment: If `numNodesWidth` happens to be initialized with `bounds.x / nodeSize.x`, rounding may cause something along those lines if the division has a remainder. Values round towards zero by default.

Comment: Something about the what you _think_ the scale transformation is doing differs from what is really happening. Debugging is about eliminating the difference. How to do that is a programming problem of its own. Common methods are logical deduction by carefully reading the code, adding logging, and using a debugger.  Asking others to do one of these in SO (here only the first is possible because you've supplied incomplete info) is another option.  But it's not a great one because you miss the opportunity for you to sharpen your own skills.

Comment: @aa *Somehow I get the vector subscript out of range 1655* -- There is no "somehow" if you wrote the code.  You had a plan in mind, you coded the plan, and now something in your program goes against your plan.  Your job is to debug the program to see where the code diverges from your plan.  The runtime is basically handing you all the information necessary to debug the problem, i.e. the vector subscript is out of range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no guarantee that `bounds <= num_nodes * node_size`. This is especially risky since there are integer divisions involved, which means that you are at the mercy of rounding.

You *could* shuffle code around until such a guarantee is present, but there's a better way.

If the `checkGraphBounds()` function operated on the same math that the grid does, you could be sure that the result would be consistent with grid, no matter how that relates to the bounds.

The ideal way to do so would be to actually use `toGraphCoords()` as part of it:

```
bool checkGraphBounds(sf::Vector2u mouseCoord, const Graph& graph, 
                      sf::Vector2f nodeSize)
{
    auto coord = toGraphCoords(mouseCoord, nodeSize);

    return coord.x >= 0 && 
           coord.y >= 0 && 
           coord.x < graph.dimensions().x && 
           coord.y < graph.dimensions().y) ;
}
```

With this, you can formally guarantee that should a `mouseCoord` pass that test, `static_cast<uint32_t>(mouseCoord.x / nodeSize.x)}` will for certain return a value no greater than `graph.dimensions().x`.

Personally, I would combine both functions as a method of `Graph` like so:

```
class Graph : public sf::Drawable {
    // Make nodeSize a member of the Graph
    sf::Vector2f nodeSize_; 

    // This is one of the cases where caching an inferable value is worth it.
    sf::Vector2u dimensions_; 

  public:
    std::optional<sf::Vector2u> toGraphCoords(sf::Vector2i mouseCoord) {
      sf::Vector2u coord{
        static_cast<uint32_t>(mouseCoord.y / nodeSize_.y), 
        static_cast<uint32_t>(mouseCoord.x / nodeSize_.x)};
      };

      // No need to compare against 0, we are dealing with unsigned ints
      if(coord.x < dimensions_.x &&
         coord.y < dimensions_.y ) {
        return coord;
      }
      return std::nullopt;
    }

    // ...
};
```

Usage:

```
void on_click(sf::Vector2i mouse_loc) {
  auto maybe_graph_coord = the_graph.toGraphCoords(mouse_loc);

  if(maybe_graph_coord) {
    sf::Vector2u graph_coord = *maybe_graph_coord;
    // ...
  }
}
```